# How to fill current-step in lightning-progress-indicator?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have this code in html:

```
    <lightning-progress-indicator id="path" current-step={currentStep} type="path" variant="base">
        <template for:each={allStages.data} for:item="stage">
            <lightning-progress-step label={stage.Name} value={stage.Name} key={stage.Name} onclick={handleClick} ></lightning-progress-step>
        </template>
    </lightning-progress-indicator>
</template>
```

Code in js:

```
    import getAllStages from '@salesforce/apex/PathController.getAllStages';
    import STAGE_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Stage__c.Name';

    export default class CustomPath extends LightningElement {
        
    @api recordId;
    @track currentStep
    @wire(getAllStages, { matterId: '$recordId', fields: [STAGE_NAME] })
    allStages;
    
    handleClick(event){
        this.currentStep = event.target.index;
        window.console.debug(this.currentStep);
    }
```

So, how can I fill `current-step={currentStep}` from js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-progress-indicator/specification) `current-step` (emphasis mine)

> Set current-step to match **the value attribute** of one of progress-step components.
> If current-step is not provided, the value of the first progress-step component is used.

So the `handleClick` method should be

```
handleClick(event){
    this.currentStep = event.target.value;
    console.debug(this.currentStep);
}
```

By the way, after Spring '20 there is no need for the `@track` decorator in such cases.
All fields in a Lightning web component class are reactive. If a field’s value changes, and the field is used in a template or in a getter of a property that’s used in a template, the component rerenders and displays the new value. More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields).

Comment: Thanks, @RubenDG, it works for me. I'm new in JS, so my questions may seem silly. However, thanks for your help!